# Routing Error Rails, dont undertand

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Are all correct but the error persists, i make the all codes to all you see

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :user_id=>#<Post id: 1, title: "sa", content: "sasa", created_at: "2013-01-06 00:25:03", updated_at: "2013-01-06 00:25:03", image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, user_id: 1>, :action=>"edit"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

My routes are:

```
  get "painel/index"

 resources :posts

  resources :user  do
    resources :posts,:comments

      end
```

and my models is:

```
user.rb

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation,:username
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments

post.rb

  attr_accessible :content, :title  ,:image
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user
```

Comment: It looks like you've got a mismatch b/n the :posts resource and the :user/:posts resource... instead of setting controller to 'posts' you probably want it to be 'user/posts'...

Please show us how you are invoking that route (ie. the link_to call...).

Answer (score 0):

1) Check 'rake routes'
2) use the url or path you get in routes list. That will solve your error

If that does not solve your error,
paste your routes file and link_to call which is returning error.